# mySQL Query - Not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem (obviously), the sql query is not successfully inserting into the table;

This is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST["newpost"])) {                                                 
    $sqlSTR = "SELECT idPhoto FROM tblhomepagephotos order by idPhoto desc LIMIT 1 INTO @myID; 
        INSERT INTO tblhomepagetext(idText, hpText) 
        VALUES (@myID, '" . $_POST["newpost"] . "')";                                            
    echo $sqlSTR;
    $result= mysql_query($sqlSTR);                                                                                  
}
```

The echo for the sqlSTR is:

```
SELECT idPhoto FROM tblhomepagephotos order by idPhoto desc LIMIT 1 INTO @myID; 
INSERT INTO tblhomepagetext(idText, hpText) VALUES (@myID, 'Text here')
```

Now the problem is that it worked perfectly and inserts into tblhomepagetext perfectely when executed from mySQL Workbench, but doesn't work when executed from the website.

Any ideas of why?

I thought it might be due to some PHP conflict where theres the ';' in the sql query.

Comment: You cannot perform more than one query. It's a security thing. Extra tips: format your code the next time, all the extra whitespace makes it hard to read, and also, please, please please don't use `mysql_query`. Read the manual: they are deprecated.

Comment: You could use mysqli_multi_query() But please note that it is the mysqli extension, not the mysql.

Comment: How much does it cost to separate the queries?

Comment: Oh thanks guys :) didn't pass my mind :) and sorry about the white spaces.

Comment: What is the most secure way to do what I need in a correct manner?

Comment: Thank you for your tips, new to PHP, and love to learn, so thanks :) changed to mySQLi.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using the `INSERT INTO SELECT` syntax incorrectly, you have the order swapped around. It should be more like:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany';
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

However, I suspect you don't require `INSERT INTO SELECT` at all. If you simply need to `INSERT` into a table then the syntax is more like this:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, City, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Stavanger', 'Norway');
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

I suggest you read through those links before proceeding

Edit: Also that semi colon in your example should not be there, that is separating the command in two. This is the reason mySQL workbench can perform the query. It is literally performing two queries sequentially. First it selects some value from your tblhomepagephotos table, then it inserts into tblhomepagephotos. You need to combine the queries as I show above. Then, PHP will be able to perform the single query.

Edit2:
There are many issues with your code its hard to tell whether you need `INSERT INTO SELECT` or not because I can't figure out your logic.
What I suggest you do is read more examples of howto perform basic `CRUD` interaction with your database (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete). I suggest you might require to first `SELECT` your photo details, THEN insert into the tblhomepagetext table. but firstly just see if the below code works. BTW, at very least you should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` as below when inserting a value via post into your database with `mysqli` . better yet is to use something like `PDO`, or learn an entire PHP framework such as `Cake, Codeigniter or Zend Framework`. These are all solutions to help with exposure to `SQL Injection`

From your latest comments, here is a solution i think your after:

```
// PERFORM Base64 PHOTO INSERT QUERY HERE 
// (I assume your already doing this as you mention from your Base64 comment.)

// Directly following the insert image query, you need to use the magical command of `mysqli_insert_id()`. 
// This will grab the latest inserted Database ID from the previous INSERT command. 
$latest_photo_id = mysqli_insert_id();

// now that we have the latest photo ID we can insert into our homepage table
if (isset($_POST["newpost"])) {
    $your_id = 1; // put a ID from your photo table here.                                      
    $sqlSTR = "INSERT INTO tblhomepagetext(idText, hpText) 
                VALUES (".$latest_photo_id.", '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["newpost"]) . "')";
    echo $sqlSTR;
    $result= mysqli_query($sqlSTR);
}
```

Comment: So can I do:

`code`INSERT INTO tblhomepagetext(idText, hpText) 
SELECT idPhoto FROM tblhomepagephotos order by idPhoto desc LIMIT 1 INTO @myID
VALUES (@myID, 'text')`code`

Or would that be invalid?

Comment: No that is not valid, if you look at my example, the columns from the INSERT and the columns 'selected' using the SELECT MUST MATCH. However, looking at your modified query, you would need to be inserting into hpText and with a value from your photo table. However, that is really a nonsense query. What are you actually trying to achieve? ie, Why are trying to insert something from the photo table, into your homepagetext table.

Comment: wired00, a user uploads a photo, and gets encoded into data64 string and added to a table with an ID, now I need to have another table called tblhomepagetext (which will have all the text etc etc) for the photo assigned; to do that I need to get the ID of the last photo, in order to then join the tables in my sql queries. :/

Comment: I've added Edit2 above

Comment: Ahh ok I understand now, well I wouldn't approach this in the way you are. A problem is that you have no guarantee that between the time you run this INSERT INTO and the last time a photo was uploaded, the SELECT to get the last ID via the LIMIT 1 command would still get the latest...what if 5 more have been uploaded...? They would never be inserted into your homepage table ;) let me get a solution for you

Comment: hehe Thanks wired00 :) for the patience... yes thats another issue !

Comment: Ok Try that latest Edit. the command you needed was `mysqli_insert_id()` followed by your homepagetext insert. see my explanation above. Thats all for me I'm off home from work